# CSS shape (square) before heading

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to put a responsive css made square before the  tag. Something like this
[image]

I've been trying to do it like this, but I can't seem to get the square to appear. Could you please help me out with this one.

```
h1::before {
position: relative;
width: 25%;
padding-bottom: 25%;
overflow: hidden;
background: red;
}
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to see a pseudoelement you need to always define its `content` property, e.g. `content: ""` : anyway in your example you should also define a `display` property.

Example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNNQrj

```
h1:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  ...
}
```

A final note about the syntax: the `::` CSS3 version is correct, but if you need to make it work also with `IE8` just use the CSS2 syntax with a single colon (`:`)

Further info available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Answer (score 1):

You need content and display set.

http://jsfiddle.net/37s1mtmk/

```
h1 { font-size:2em;}
h1::before {
width: 1em;
height:1em;
background: red;
display:inline-block;
content: "";
margin-right: 10px;
}
```